# string(53) "user_name=test&password=471476&sessionId=1&userType=1" how to get this values in array

Tags: php

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

this code give value like given below

```
string(53) "user_name=test&password=471476&sessionId=1&userType=1"
```

I need to insert the values in table.

how can I insert the values?

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $postdata);
print_r($keywords);
```

Comment: Fun Fact: When you submit a form via GET the values usually get logged in the web server logs, so if you're submitting logins via GET you've got a nice log full of plaintext credentials prime for stealing/leaking. Use POST.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Theres a builtin function:
[parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: this is not an answer to the question; this is at best a comment.

Comment: @jibsteroos The question was, how to parse a query string and this is the answer. The length of a answer does not determine if its a comment or not. And even the marked as duplicate states what I do in my answer.

Comment: it's working... great thank you so much